# Create Folder during compute copy-files

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to copy a file from my laptop to the Compute Instance. Can i copy the file to a folder which does not exists but is created during the copy?

Example: 
I have a file index.php and i want to copy it to /var/www/test
The folder test is not present.

When i run a command:

```
gcloud compute copy-files index.php user@instance-1:/var/www/test
```

It does not give any error. But when i ssh into the instance it shows test under /var/www but

```
cd /var/www/test
```

gives me:

```
-bash: cd: test: Not a directory
```

How can i create a directory and then copy a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting set of circumstances leading to surprising results. To understand what's going on, it's useful to know that the `gcloud compute copy-files` command runs the scp command under the covers.

In this case, the scp command is interpreting `/var/www/test` as a destination path.  Because `/var/www` exists, but `/var/www/test` does not, it's interpreting the `test` portion as the name of the file you want to save on the remote machine.  So it's dutifully copying the contents of `index.php` into a file called `/var/www/test` on the remote machine.

To get the results you want, you should remove the file (with `rm /var/www/test`), and create a directory (with `mkdir /var/www/test`).  If you were starting with a fresh machine, you could achieve the desired result like this:

```
gcloud compute ssh user@instance-1 --command='mkdir /var/www/test'
gcloud compute copy-files index.php user@instance-1:/var/www/test
```